# can I use .to_s(:long) in Postgres with a column type date on Heroku in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, heroku

I have a column type date (shown from annotate) on my Contacts table:

```
#  date_entered       :date(255)
```

This is the line of code that has worked for me locally on my sqlite3 database, but now generates an error in Heroku:

```
<%= contact.date_entered.to_s(:long) %>
```

The error that I get is:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I removed the `:long` component and it appears to work, but now, of course, looks badly formatted.

How do I address this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

for date formatting.

Also you can override to_s method for Date/Time to use I18n localization:

```
class Date
  def to_s format = :default
    I18n.l(self, :format => format)
  end
end
```

In this case can use both :logn (:default, :short) and '%d %B, %Y' formats.

**UPD:**
Also it makes sense to store old method and call it in case you don't pass any params:

```
class Date
  alias :to_s :native_to_s

  def to_s format = nil
    format.nil? ? 
      self.native_to_s : 
      I18n.l(self, :format => format)
  end
end
```

Comment: Date.to_s just don't have any arguments by default. (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Date.html#M000685)
But as I wrote above it could be overriden

Comment: outside of overriding...why would you suggest using date.strftime?  Just more granulary?  I'd have to repeat it every time though in the controller?

Comment: I suggested strftime method since it was designed for date formating, so this case (with strftime) - yes, you'll have to repeat it every time. It should be OK if you need it rarely, otherwise you'd better override to_s method. I've updated code a little - take a look at the my answer.

Comment: okay, cool, this is good...interesting to override it.  I would just put it into a date.rb file in lib?

Answer (score 0):

Is that actually a postgres date field?

```
end_date           | date
```

is what postgres has as a date field, can you check on the table itself? Also sticking `contact.date_entered.class` somewhere in a view to find out what the exact Ruby class is.

I have a huge hunch that it is not a timestamp or date field. Most likely actually a text or varchar and thus ActiveRecord interprets it that way.

Comment: Can't say for sure without having a look myself, have you found out what the class of the "timestamp" you are trying to display is?